# Data structure for handling intervals and point query

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to know a data structure which allows me to

1) Add an interval and cost of it

2) Extract the minimum cost of each point in the global interval [1,N]

It is possible no interval covers a point in that case return INT_MAX .

I have tried to modify segment Tree using Lazy propagation. I am making a decision at every point should I update it or not? It is not working ?

Can I use the sparse table here?

Comment: That's called a "weighed graph".

Comment: In a weighted graph you add an edge between two vertices I am talking about adding an interval say [L,R] which has a cost C ! Now there are several intervals which have different Cost (They are overlapping indeed). Now I want to merge them and find the minimum at each point!

Comment: How have you modified a segment tree? Are you asking us whether your modification of segment tree is not working?

Comment: I am rather asking how to do it? Can we do it using a segment Tree?
All I do in the segment tree is that when the interval is directly in the range I mark it's children with this value. I mean to say that I update only when the update value is lesser than the node value. All the node's are irrelevant except when they are the leaf nodes. All the values will tend to reach the Leaves by the means of lazy propagation when I will try to extract value of that leaf. That should be the minimum value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically sounds like you need an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) mapping intervals to costs.

1. To add an interval, you simply add to the tree another entry.
2. To perform the query you write, you ask the tree to return all entries which a intersect a given point; given this list, return infinity if it is empty, otherwise its minimum.

The complexity of the first query is logarithmic in the number of intervals. The complexity of the second query is logarithmic in the number of intervals + linear in the number of intersecting intervals.

(BTW, I've implemented this sort of stuff for Python in the [Banyan package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Banyan/0.1.5).)